# How do I call the route defined by the Plug.Router macro at runtime?

Tags: elixir, plug

Can I manually build a `conn` and then call them like a function? If you don't understand what "them" means, look at the code below.

For example, define a route `/ping`

```
get "/ping" do
  send_resp(conn, 200, "pong")
end
```

I know that it can be done with the `conn` function in `use Plug.Test`, but it is based on the HTTP Client, not a runtime function call, which is too inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is as you said, to use [`Plug.Test.conn/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Test.html#conn/3) to build a `%Plug.Conn{}` struct that will cause that route to be called.

All plugs have a [`call/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.html#c:call/2) function, which is what's available at runtime.

Example:

```elixir
conn = Plug.Test.conn(:get, "/ping", "")
conn = YourModule.Router.call(conn, [])
```

The `get` macro is [compiled](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Router.html#module-routes-compilation) at compile-time into a private `match/3` function, which itself is called by the `call/2` function and also requires the `conn` struct. So you have to use the `call/2` callback for runtime testing, unless you call `match/3` from inside your router module. `Plug.Test.conn/3` does not use an HTTP Client - it's just produces a struct. I think your concerns about inefficiency are unfounded.

Comment: Yes, the `conn` function only generate a struct. But is `MyModule.Router.call` based on an HTTP client? Sorry, this is just my subconscious speculation.

Comment: No, `call/2` is just a regular function call. That function is eventually called when your application handles an HTTP request - in that case the adapter (probably `plug_cowboy`) handles producing the `conn` for you - but there's no reason you can't also make your own `conn` using `Plug.Test.conn/3` and call `call` directly.